# How to make sure that accessibility options are accessible

Tags: html, accessibility, user-experience

Many webpages have options where you can change the font size or increase contrast. Those options are most of time designed for visually impaired people.

What technics do you use to ensure that those people actually find the options to increase accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WCAG 2.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20160317/G174), a high-contrast toggle must itself be high-contrast. I've done this simply by creating simple black-on-white button (that inverts when hovered of focussed, for effect) at the head of my page. I opted to use a font-awesome icon for the button content, so I was careful to include `role="img"` and `aria-label="High Contrast Toggle"` in the `<i>`. I was also careful to make the toggle keyboard-accessible by adding a `tabindex`

It's better to make all text high-contrast by default, but I opted for the toggle as a learning challenge and also because I did not want to change my page's colour scheme. Alternatives to toggles that are suggested by the spec are using [skrims or text-shadow](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20160317/G18). (description, 3rd paragraph). This would have looked and worked better, but my testing tools (WAVE Chrome extension v. 1.0.1) didn't detect the change, so I decided to make a toggle.

Comment: Note that the linked [G174](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20160317/G174) is not from the WCAG 2.0 specification ([/WCAG20/](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)), but from the note *Techniques for WCAG 2.0* ([/WCAG20-TECHS/](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/)). Those techniques [are not normative/required](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/67254/17023), they just document one of possibly many ways how to achieve something in an accessible way.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide such widgets, you have to make sure that your document is also accessible *without* using them. Otherwise (= your document is inaccessible with the default settings) some users can’t find/reach/use your widgets to change the settings.

If you can’t make your whole document accessible without using the widgets, you should at least make sure that the widgets can be reached and used. This would be similar to providing a [link to an alternate version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149721/1591669).

As far as I know, there is no standard way to mark up or annotate such accessibility-related widgets. If they are important, it can make sense to have them as one of the first elements of the document.

(And just in case it’s not clear: it’s rarely *necessary* to provide such widgets, [e.g., for text resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166988/1591669), at all; there are often many other ways/technologies to make sure that your document is accessible.)